# How to do custom searchview in LinearLayout like in action bar

Tags: android

I want to implement in Linear Layout search view like in action bar. I want to achieve get back button icon into search view how we did in action bar.Any idea will be appreciate
Like this 
[image: my pickture]

My layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        >
    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/sv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:queryHint="Поиск по каталогу"

        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.SearchView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list_result">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <com.github.rahatarmanahmed.cpv.CircularProgressView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/progress_view"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        app:cpv_animAutostart="true"
        app:cpv_indeterminate="true"
        cpv_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is the problem then???

Comment: @jankigadhiya How can I implement into searchview back button?

Comment: make it custom in a linear Layout..!!

Comment: @jankigadhiya ok I will try it. And will share what I will get